# How do I change permissions in google compute so node can write files?

Tags: node.js, linux, nginx, permissions, google-compute-engine

In node app hosted on google compute when node app tries to make a directory for uploads it gets:

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/html/app/xlsx'
```

So I used the google compute browser SSH console and ran `sudo mkdir xlsx` so now the directory is there, but the file uploads are still failing. How do I give the node instance permission to write to the file system?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer here: [node application getting "Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '.tmp'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36435434/node-application-getting-error-eacces-permission-denied-mkdir-tmp)

Needed to use node.js `os.tmpdir()` with multer

```
let upload = multer({dest: `${os.tmpdir()}/xlsx/`});
```

Answer (score 1):

use 'sudo' command while executing. This enables the Root User privileges for you.

sudo mkdir '/var/www/html/app/xlsx'

Comment: that's what I did to make the directory... but the app still needs to create files when they are uploaded and that is still failing.. I'm using multer for that https://github.com/expressjs/multer